# ¿Cómo puedo leer un número de dos dígitos con 2 switch uno para decenas y otro para unidades?

Tags: php

```
<?
$numero=$_POST['numero'];
$decena=$numero/10;
$unidad;
$decena;
$unidad=$numero%10;


switch($decena)
{
case 2:
echo "veinte";
break;

case 3:
echo "treinta";
break;

case 4:
echo "cuarenta";
break;

case 5:
echo "cincuenta";
break;

case 6:
echo "sesenta";
break;

case 7:
echo "setenta";
break;

case 8:
echo "ochenta";
break;

case 9:
echo "noventa";
break;

case 10:
echo "cien";
break;
default:
}

switch($unidad)
{
case 1:
echo "uno";
break;
case 2:
echo "dos";
break;
case 3:
echo "tres";
break;
case 4:
echo "cuatro";
break;
case 5:
echo "cinco";
break;
case 6:
echo "seis";
break;
case 7:
echo "siete";
break;
case 8:
echo "ocho";
break;
case 9:
echo "nueve";
break;
}

?>
```

Comment: ¿Obtiene algún error su código? ¿no funciona como debería ?

Comment: El posible detalle sería que `$numero/10` retorna un `float` , debería aplicar `intval($numero/10)`

Comment: Jorge, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Podrías por favor dar más detalles de tu pregunta? Si es posible, poner un ejemplo de algún número y de lo que quieres lograr. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El único detalle que haría que funcione correctamente su código sería que `$numero/10` retorna un `float` , debería aplicar `intval($numero/10)`

```
$decena= intval($numero/10);
$unidad=$numero%10;
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias.